# How to use Feed_Xpath module in drupal?

Tags: xpath, drupal-7

I was trying to fetch the Dspace conetent into Drupal.

I found a way .I have RestFulWebServices(Xmls) with me.

I have installed Feed Xpath module in Drupal7.

I have given Import Url as  " http://library.leadingtochoices.org/dspace-rest-1.8.1/collections.xml "

and As Xpath Parser Setting :
 Contecxt : /collections
 Title    : /collection
 body     :/communities/name

it will came with whole xml not the queired one.

I want to know only the name Attribute ,but it came with whole file.

Please let me know how to use Feed Xpath module.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Context : //collection

Title : body

Body : name